# How to have a non-integer version code display on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am using ionic5 to to build an app, but I am struggling to figure out how I can set the version name to be a .dot release for both iOS and Android.

Although I am following the guidelines outlined in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/ I am still unable to get the dot release to show up in Android.

Below is the head of my config.xml

```
<widget android-versionName="001" id="abm.app.response" ios-CFBundleVersion="0.0.1" version="3.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

However, while it works on iOS, ... no matter what I try, I can't get the ".dot" version code to display on Android.  See screenshots.

Any advice?

[iOS vs Android version codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LPAI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself.  It seems that this cannot be done.   I simply used a single integer value in the widget, and it worked.

```
<widget android-versionCode="1" id="abm.app.response" ios-CFBundleVersion="1" version="3.1"
```